# Terraform Add new key/value into a existing list of map from another map

Tags: terraform

I have following terraform maps

```html
locals {
  accounts = [
    {
      "id" = "111111111111"
      "status" = "ACTIVE"
    },
    {
      "id" = "222222222222"
      "status" = "ACTIVE"
    }
  ]

  account_map   = {
      111111111111 = "DEV"
      222222222222 = "PROD"
    }
}
```

I want to create another list of map from these two variables as below

```html
accounts = [
  {
    "id" = "11111111111"
    "status" = "ACTIVE"
    "type" = "DEV" 
  },
  {
    "id" = "222222222222"
    "status" = "ACTIVE"
    "type" = "PROD"
  }
]
```

I tried as below. But the problem is it will create lot of duplicates. Can anyone please help me with this.

```html
  account_info = flatten([
    for account in local.accounts : [
      for type in local.account_map : {
        id   = account.id
        type = type
      }
  ]])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that as follows:

```
 locals {
   
  account_info = [
    for account in local.accounts:
      merge(account, {type = local.account_map[account.id]})
  ]
    
}
```

Comment: If you could help me with below as this is relatd to the same. That would be really helpful. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72773833/terraform-conditionally-create-aws-cloudformation-stack-instances

Answer (score 0):

A different way to solve this in my case:

```
locals {
  map_to_extend = {
    list_one = {
      element_one = "string1"
      element_two = "string2"
    }
    list_two = {
      element_one = "string3"
      element_two = "string4"
    }
  }

  map_to_merge = {
     list_one = true
     list_two = false
  }

  merged_map = {
    for key, value in map_to_extend :
      key => merge(value, { apply_list = local.map_to_merge[key] }
  }
```

Result:

```
merged_map = {
    list_one = {
      element_one = "string1"
      element_two = "string2"
      apply_list = true
    }
    list_two = {
      element_one = "string3"
      element_two = "string4"
      apply_list = false
    }
  }
```