# Terraform conditionally create AWS CloudFormation StackSet instances

Tags: terraform

I have following `stask_set_instance` module and it works pretty will when we passes `var.accounts` from my root module.

```html
instance_data = flatten([
    for account in var.accounts : [
      for region in var.regions : {
        account = account.id
        region  = region
      }
    ]
  ])

resource "aws_cloudformation_stack_set_instance" "stack" {
  for_each = {
    for stack_instance in local.instance_data
  }
  account_id          = each.value.account
  region              = each.value.region
  parameter_overrides = {}
  stack_set_name      = aws_cloudformation_stack_set.stackset.name
}
```

Now I want to conditionally handle from my child module to override `var.stackset_parameter_overrides` depends on my AWS account type (You can consider type as an environment DEV | STG | PROD ).

For that, now I have updated my locals variables as below. Where `type` will have the account Tag to identify the AWS account type (Environment). (I used `Try` to set type null because there is another resource block in my root module, which I cannot pass type as it use different input). But in this example, we can assume the module always get a value for type.

```html
accounts = [
  {
    "id" = "11111111111"
    "status" = "ACTIVE"
    "type" = "DEV" 
  },
  {
    "id" = "222222222222"
    "status" = "ACTIVE"
    "type" = "PROD"
  }
]

region = ["us-east-1", "us-west-2"]

instance_data = flatten([
    for account in var.accounts : [
      for region in var.regions : {
        account = account.id
        type    = try(length(account.type), 0) > 0 ? account.type : null
        region  = region
      }
    ]
  ])
```

Now I want to know how can I conditionally override my `parameter_overrides` variable values based on the `type` varialbe. (I can pass `parameter_overrides` from a different variable from my root module). What I want to know is how to handle `aws_cloudformation_stack_set_instance` module to change this behaviour depends on the account type.

We can assume `type` is equivalent to `DEV` | `STG` | `PROD`. Therefore, depends on the type, I will have to change the `parameter_overrides` values.

Comment: What are `accounts` and `regions` variables?

Comment: Thanks @Marcin for the comment. I updated the question accordingly. I also came up with a solution like I posted below. Feel free to comment if you see any concern on that.

Answer (score 0):

Just positing my solution here, to comment on any improvements or to help someone in feature.

```html
patch_manager_params = {
  DEV = {
    "Para1" = 0
    "Para2" = 0
    "Para3" = 0
  },
  PROD = {
    "Para1" = 0
    "Para2" = 0
    "Para3" = 0
  }
}


resource "aws_cloudformation_stack_set_instance" "stack" {
  for_each = {
    for stack_instance in local.instance_data
  }
  account_id          = each.value.account
  region              = each.value.region
  parameter_overrides = lookup(var.parameter_overrides, each.value.type, null)
  stack_set_name      = aws_cloudformation_stack_set.stackset.name
}
```